# How to efficiently access a Python iterable indexes provenient from another iterable

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, numpy

I have a list `X` and a list `Y` where there are some shuffled indexes.

```
X = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e']
Y = [ 1 ,  3 ,  4 ,  0 , 2 ]
```

I want to have a new list `Z` such that

```
Z = [ X[i] for i in Y ] = ['b', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'c']
```

The issue is that i have to do this multiple times, for such big `arrays`. There is any more efficient approach than the list-by-comprehension for loops?

**Note:** `numpy` solutions are apreciated!

Comment: `X = np.array(X); result = X[Y]`, also it seems your "expected output" is incorrect.

Comment: THANKS!! I guess the question is closed.

Comment: No, the output is actually correct.

Comment: ..."provenient"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) accepts multiple indices, one solution is:

```
>>> import operator
>>> operator.itemgetter(*Y)(X)
('b', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'c')
```

The efficient one (as posted in comments) would be via `numpy`'s array indexing:

```
np.array(X)[Y]
```

but **only** if `X` and `Y` are converted to `numpy.array` once (ahead of use) and used many times.

---

#### Performance tests

Indexing `1k` elements (`Y`) from a list of `1M` elements (`X`).

```
# setup
import random
import numpy as np
X = [random.randint(0,100) for i in range(1000000)]
Y = [random.randint(0,1000000) for i in range(1000)]
```

#### 1) List comprehension ~ 34 µs

```
%timeit [X[i] for i in Y]
10000 loops, best of 3: 34 µs per loop
```

#### 2) `itemgetter` ~ 16.6 µs

```
%timeit operator.itemgetter(*Y)(X)
100000 loops, best of 3: 16.6 µs per loop
```

#### 3) `numpy`, arrays converted on fly ~ 31.6 ms   ⇒   slowest

```
%timeit np.array(X)[Y]
10 loops, best of 3: 31.6 ms per loop
```

#### 4) `numpy`, arrays pre-converted ~ 1.72 µs   ⇒   fastest

```
x = np.array(X)
y = np.array(Y)
%timeit x[y]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.72 µs per loop
```

Comment: In timetests, `itemgetter` is fastest.  list comprehension about half its speed. and array even slower.  Array approaches the list comprehension speed if `X` is already an array.

Comment: @hpaulj, cool, let me update the answer with some tests then.

Answer (score 2):

Convert your lists to NumPy arrays and use the second as the index for the first:

```
x, y = np.array(x), np.array(y)
Z = x[y]
```